# Android Studio Launch Times

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

Somewhere around Android Studio 2.x I started to notice a palpable increase in the amount of time it takes to launch Android Studio -- both on Mac and Windows.

Currently, it takes several minutes to load Android Studio when my PC is first turned on.  After that of course there is some caching and load time is "only" around a minute.  Still, that seems kinda nuts given I'm all SSD.  My computers are several years old, but still...

My question is whether this is a known issue, experienced by all Android developers, or if it's something specific to my environment.  Since I run Android Studio on four different computers (2 PC, 2 Mac) and it's consistently slow to load on each of them, I presume so far that it's a common problem.  If so, any word on whether or not Google is going to focus on fixing it in the near future?

Comment: doesnt happen for me what are you pc specs? then again i never shutdown my laptop to begin with

Comment: I guess try shutting it off then on again and see what happens?  I notice it more than any other on my Surface Pro 4.